# Duvida sobre arrays e ponteiro

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main () {

    setlocale (LC_ALL,"Portuguese"); // Formatação.

    int notas1[50],notas2[50],notas3[50],soma[50]; // Declaração.

    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++){ // Dados.
        printf("\nInforme a primeira nota do aluno %i: ",i);
        scanf("%i",&notas1[i]);
        printf("\nInforme a segunda nota do aluno %i: ",i);
        scanf("%i",&notas2[i]);
        printf("\nInforme a terceira nota do aluno %i: ",i);
        scanf("%i",&notas3[i]); }

    for (int h = 1; h < 50; h++){ // Soma e divisão dos vetores 1,2 e 3 para cada nota.
        soma[h] = (notas1[h] + notas2 [h] + notas3 [h])/3; }

    for (int j = 1; j < 50; j++){ // Imprimindo.
        printf ("\nA nota do aluno %i é: %i",j,soma[j]); }

    return 0;
}
```

Minhas duvidas são : Como eu faria pra pedir o número de vetores a ser criado para o usuário e depois guardar na variável para continuar o programa ( sem fazer com ponteiro ) ?  Como ficaria o código extremamente simplificado ou melhor como ficaria esse código só que feito com ponteiro ( eu tentei mas não dei conta ).

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode clicar no **V** ao lado da resposta para marcar sua pergunta como respondida.

Comment: Já marquei vlw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como em `C` é possível declarar variáveis em qualquer parte do código, tem como solicitar o valor e depois declarar seus vetores. Exemplo:

```
int vec_len;
scanf("%d", &vec_len);

int notas1[vec_len],notas2[vec_len],notas3[vec_len],soma[vec_len];
```

Mas para simplificar o código, seria melhor colocar todas as notas em uma matriz

```
int notas[vec_len][4]; // a quarta posição de notas serve para a soma das notas
```

Agora para o uso dos ponteiros, só muda a parte de ter que alocar de desalocar.

```
int vec_len;
scanf("%d", &vec_len);

int *notas1 = malloc(vec_len*sizeof(int));
int *notas2 = malloc(vec_len*sizeof(int));
int *notas3 = malloc(vec_len*sizeof(int));
int *soma = malloc(vec_len*sizeof(int));
```

O `sizeof(int)` serve alocar o tamanho exato compatível com valores inteiros.

E a simplificação.

```
int **notas = malloc(vec_len*sizeof(int*)); // matriz ou ponteiro duplo
int x;
for(x=0;x<vec_len;x++)
    notas[x] = malloc(4*sizeof(int));
```

Em `**notas` possui o `sizeof(int*)` por que está pegando o tamanho de `int*` para alocar, e `notas[x]` representa `int*` e guarda valores `int`.

Se for usar vetores, não tem a necessidade fazer alterações na inserção dos valores. Já se for usar matriz fica `notas[x][y]`.

Para desalocar os ponteiros basta fazer.

```
//Caso seja uma matriz
//...
free(notas[x]);
//...
free(notas);
```

---

```
//Caso seja vetor
free(notas1);
free(notas2);
free(notas3);
free(soma);
```

Comment: Na parte " int *notas1 = malloc ", não é obrigatório colocar o  int entre parenteses não ? muito obrigado por tirar um tempo pra responder !!!

Comment: Na verdade não há necessidade, alguns autores dizem não ser uma boa pratica, outros dizem que é bom colocar. colocar o `(int *)` é mais algo voltado para semântica do código. ter ou não, não faz diferença no caso do malloc.

Comment: Rs rs eu sei, mas tenho um toc infernal ! kkkk